How can I center multiple alignment points in an equation inside an align environment?
Courtesy link: How can I center an equation inside an align environment?

A single equation in align is centered, so with gather
you get both equations centered; otherwise, nest align inside gather.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

A single equation in \texttt{align} is centered, so with > \texttt{gather}
you get both equations centered:
\begin{gather}
a = b + c
a = b + c \quad a = b + c
\end{gather}
If you have \emph{two} equations to align with each other and
one to be centered, nest \texttt{align} in \texttt{gather}
\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
a &= b + c\\
x &= b + c + d + e
\end{align}\\
a = b + c \quad a = b + c \quad a = b + c
\end{gather}

\end{document}



How can I center multiple alignment points and take up less space by overlapping the gaps? Basically, how do I print equations in the following format:
a = b + c x = y
x = b + c + d + e u = v + w
a = b + c a = b + c a = b + c

please show an example of the output you want and a small complete test file

Please only ask genuine question. Don't copy other questions just because you are under the impression that you have to ask a question on the current site of the day. Remember that the people here use their free time in order to help people who really have a question.

This could possibly be a genuine question if you would include the code you used to make the "Example" image.  But it would also help if your contribution was more than a single sentence tacked onto the end of someone else's question.  Could you elaborate what you mean by that sentence?

The added image is not really clear. See my update.

@Arunabh If you have an edit that will help your question become more clear, then please make it.  Otherwise, please don't make a single character edit just to bump the question back onto the main page.

Just for fun, why not align the first and last terms with the others?  \mathclap and \mathrlap are from the mathtools package, and are there to take up less space by overlapping the gaps.  The 5em space was found by trial and error.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &= b + c &&& x&=y\\
x &= b + c + d + e &&& u&=v+w\\
a &= b + c & a &= b + c & a &= b + c
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a &= b + c &&& x&=y\\
x &= b + c + d + e &&& u&=v+w\\
a &= b + c &&\mathclap{a = b + c} & a &= b + c
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a &= b + c & x&=y\\
x &= b + c + d + e & u&=v+w\\
a &= b + c \mathrlap{\hspace{5em} a = b + c} & a &= b + c
\end{align}

\end{document}



In align you can have multiple alignment points, but you can also use alignat.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

A single equation in \texttt{align} is centered, so with > \texttt{gather}
you get both equations centered:
\begin{gather}
a = b + c
a = b + c \quad a = b + c
\end{gather}
If you have \emph{two} equations to align with each other and
one to be centered, nest \texttt{align} in \texttt{gather}
\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
a &= b + c & x&=y\\
x &= b + c + d + e & u&=v+w
\end{align}\\
a = b + c \quad a = b + c \quad a = b + c
\end{gather}

A single equation in \texttt{align} is centered, so with > \texttt{gather}
you get both equations centered:
\begin{gather}
a = b + c
a = b + c \quad a = b + c
\end{gather}
If you have \emph{two} equations to align with each other and
one to be centered, nest \texttt{align} in \texttt{gather}
\begin{gather}
\begin{alignat}{2}
a &= b + c &\qquad x&=y\\
x &= b + c + d + e &\qquad u&=v+w
\end{alignat}\\
a = b + c \qquad a = b + c \qquad a = b + c
\end{gather}

\end{document}


Update
After seeing the edit, you may consider alignat.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
a &= b + c &\qquad&&\qquad x&=y \\
x &= b + c + d + e &&& u&=v+w \\
a &= b + c & a &= b + c & a &= b + c
\end{alignat}

\end{document}


